# How Can I Increase the Probability of a Mystery Room Appearing in the Item World?

Tags: ps2, disgaea-2

In Disgaea 2, there anything I can do to increase the probability of a Mystery Room appearing when I go through the Item World?

Comment: Are you talking about Disgaea 2?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  The site was having trouble as I was posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [as Artless indicated](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5497/how-can-i-increase-the-probability-of-a-mystery-room-appearing-in-the-item-world/5509#5509), Mystery Rooms show up every 3 floors.

Can you increase the probability that one shows up on every 3 floors? **No.** The chance is fixed.

You can, however, "fix" yourself a 100% probability if you have a spare Mr. Gency's Exit. Once you have cleared 3 floors (wherein the first floor had a Mystery Gate), then the next floor is eligible for a Mystery Gate if it isn't a boss floor. If you don't get a Mystery Gate when you first enter that floor, then use the Mr. Gency's Exit to leave the Item World, and save your game. Upon your return to the Item World, the floor will change, and a new chance for a Mystery Gate is rolled. If this also fails, then you reload your save and try again. It usually doesn't take that many tries, the chance isn't particularly low.

If you're trying to maximize an item by getting every Mystery Gate, you're going to need a lot of doors and a lot of patience. So make sure to save up!

Comment: I had thought that I needed to exit the Item World on the floor *before* the floor where a Mystery Gate may appear.  But I can exit on the floor where a Mystery Gate may appear (and has not appeared), and have a new chance at a Mystery Gate when I re-enter that item?

Comment: @KatieK Exiting before the stage is required for the special items carried by the Item Gods, but not for Mystery Gates, from my recollection of how I did it. I can't test it right now, but I could certainly do it tonight.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to happen after every three floors (clear or skip).

Here's the wiki page for it:

http://disgaea.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Gate

Comment: A Mystery Room *may* appear 3 floors after the last one appears.  I'd like to increase the chance that they do appear.